# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `preferences[19].category` of value `MemberBenefitInterests` supplied to `SettingsPage`

Tags: reactjs, state, react-devtools

I am working on a React-Redux microservice application that I am still becoming familiar with and immediately upon cloning it and booting it up in localhost environment, I see this error in the console:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `preferences[19].category` of value `MemberBenefitInterests` supplied to `SettingsPage`, expected one of ["None","CommunicationPreferences","MemberPrivacy","GetInvolved","TopicsOfConcern"].
```

Nowhere in the project is there a `MemberBenefitInterests` referenced in the codebase, however this property does exist in State when I checked React Web DevTools its in **entities**->**preferences**-> which has an array of objects:

```
{ "category": "CommunicationPreferences" }, { "category": "MemberPrivacy" }, { "category": "GetInvolved" }, { "category": "MemberBenefitsInterests" }
```

all inside preferences. I am unclear, but it seems the message is saying the last one is invalid, but why?

I thought I did a thorough search for a `SettingsPage` in the project and did not find one, but when I tried again, I found this inside of `App/account/components/BaseSettingsPage`:

```
class SettingsPage extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    isLoading: PropTypes.bool,
    currentUser: PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.string,
    }),
    pageColor: PropTypes.shape({
      name: PropTypes.string,
      value: PropTypes.string,
    }),
    headerText: PropTypes.string,
    renderSaveButton: PropTypes.func,
    handleSaveResults: PropTypes.func,
    category: PropTypes.oneOf([
      'None',
      'CommunicationPreferences',
      'MemberPrivacy',
      'GetInvolved',
      'TopicsOfConcern',
    ]),
```

Comment: can you include the proptype declaration for SettingsPage in your question?

Comment: @madebydavid, nevermind, will do.

Comment: I think you know how to solve this now :-)

Comment: @madebydavid, I found it. Looking at it, is it as straightforward as adding whats in State to the `SettingsPage` class component? Its a bit frustrating looking for things in this application. They name a component `NamedComponent` and then call the actual file `index.js`, not helpful.

Comment: yes I would add `MemberBenefitInterests` to the PropTypes declaration for that `SettingsPage` component

Comment: @madebydavid, thank you. Do you want to provide an answer for me to check off or should i just delete this post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need to adjust the PropTypes declaration for the `category` of `SettingsPage` to include `MemberBenefitInterests`:

```
    category: PropTypes.oneOf([
      'None',
      'CommunicationPreferences',
      'MemberPrivacy',
      'GetInvolved',
      'TopicsOfConcern',
      'MemberBenefitInterests',
    ]),
```